Error thrown by discord snowtransfer: [ERROR] Error when sending Discord DM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
I was using snowtransfer discord client for sending the messages to the users from my bot. It works well for the most part but while sending the dm to one of the users I got this error:
[ERROR] Error when sending Discord DM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
This error broke the application while in production. I would like it so that this issue doesn't happen in future and doesn't break the bot. Has anyone here encountered this issue before? Since I am kinda unable to reproduce it at the moment.
Here's the code snippet from where the error might be coming from
export async function sendDiscordDM(userId: string, message: string) {
  const client = new SnowTransfer(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
  try {
    const dm = await client.user.createDirectMessageChannel(userId);
    await client.channel.createMessage(dm.id, { content: message });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error when sending Discord DM: ${err}`);
  }
}

As suggested in the code above, it breaks at dm.id which means that dm is undefined. For some reason I am unable to reproduce this. I would like to know the reason behind why it would have happened so that it doesn't break on my prod bot again. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Looking through the documentation there seems to be nothing wrong with this code. Could it be that you're passing a wrong userId? I think that would give a API error. Other than that there seems to be nothing wrong with the code. One other thing could be that if the user doesn't allow DM's which I doubt because you should be able to create a DM still, just not able to send a message. Check out these two things.
